# CSS Margin-right has no effect?

Tags: css, position, margin

In below program why margin-right value (+ve/-ve) has no impact on the tooltiptext? The margin-left works fine but margin-right has no impact? Thanks

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Bottom Tooltip</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You'd need to add left or right position values fror this to work as I recall.

Comment: @Paulie_D sorry didn't get you

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/mbarem/pen/ZMgwbg

Answer (score 0):

By default HTML elements are aligned to top left corner of their parent element which in this case is `.tooltip`. Adding a `margin-right` would **push** the elements on the right away. However there are no elements after `.tooltip` thus no effect.